# Trabalhando layout no Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Só eu está tendo dificuldades para formatar as telas de layout no Android Studio depois da versão 3.0.0 ou não estou mais sabendo como fazer?

Minhas telas, são em sua maioria, uma ScrollView. Para acessar os objetos na parte de baixo, claro, uso o scroll do mouse. Antes tinha uma barra de rolagem que facilitava.

Pior que quando estou posicionado lá em baixo e altero uma propriedade do objeto na tela de atributos ele faz um refresh e posiciona novamente lá em cima.

Se você estiver ajustando os pesos dos objetos dentro do layout terá muitas dificuldades.

É isso mesmo ou eu perdi alguma coisa?

Abaixo segue um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como colocar os seus  xmls e sua view da IDE que está utilizando, você está fazendo com position absolute?

Comment: Reginaldo, percebi isto tbm! O que faço quando estou trabalhando na parte de baixo, é setar **android:visibility="gone"** no componentes acima! Geralmente o **ScrollView** tem um **LinearLayout** dentro! Já na parte de setar os pesos é bem chato mesmo ! (estou na 3.0.1)

Comment: Eu to com uns bug na edição de layout tb, principalmente no constraint layout, mas não mexi com scroll view ainda

Comment: Deve ser algum bug da IDE. Por isso eu sempre demoro pra atualizar